# How to add a button in infowindow with google-maps-react?

Tags: reactjs

I want to integrate a button in my infowindow. It appears and I can click it but it doesn't trigger the onClick.

This is details text for post, i dont think i can more explain this.This is details text for post, i dont think i can more explain this.This is details text for post, i dont think i can more explain this.

My code:

```
export class MapPage extends Component {
  state = {
    activeMarker: {},
    selectedPlace: {},
    selectedText: {},
    selectedId: {},
    showingInfoWindow: false
  };

  send = () => {

      console.log('fzf');

}    

  onMarkerClick = (props, marker) => {
    this.setState({
      activeMarker: marker,
      selectedPlace: props,
      selectedText: props,
      selectedId: props,
      showingInfoWindow: true
    });  
  };

  onInfoWindowClose = () =>
    this.setState({
      activeMarker: null,
      showingInfoWindow: false
    });

  onMapClicked = () => {
    if (this.state.showingInfoWindow)
      this.setState({
        activeMarker: null,
        showingInfoWindow: false
      });
  };

  handleClick = () => {
    this.setState({ open: true });
  };

  handleClose = (event, reason) => {
    if (reason === 'clickaway') {
      return;
    }

    this.setState({ open: false });
  };

  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;


    return (
      <div>
        <Map google={this.props.google} 
             onClick={this.onMapClicked}
             zoom={13} 
             initialCenter={{
             lat: 48.724865087482755,
             lng: -3.4469044744779467
                          }}
        >

         <Marker>
          name='Paris'
          onClick={this.onMarkerClick}
          position={{ lat: 48, lng: -3 }}
        />

        <InfoWindow
          marker={this.state.activeMarker}
          onClose={this.onInfoWindowClose}
          visible={this.state.showingInfoWindow}>
          <div>
            <h2>{this.state.selectedPlace.name}</h2>
            <p>{this.state.selectedPlace.description}</p>
            <button type="button" onClick={this.send}>Click Me</button>

          </div>
        </InfoWindow>
        </Map>
        </div>
    );
  }
}

export default GoogleApiWrapper({
  apiKey: ('APIKEY')
})(MapPage)
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The way how [`InfoWindow` component](https://github.com/fullstackreact/google-maps-react/blob/master/src/components/InfoWindow.js) is implemented in `google-maps-react` library does not support to attach event handlers to *info window dynamic content*. The similar issue has been discussed in [this thread](https://github.com/fullstackreact/google-maps-react/issues/70).

The solution would be *render InfoWindow children into a DOM node* in order to prevent losing the React context, the following component could be introduced for that matter:

```
export default class InfoWindowEx extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.infoWindowRef = React.createRef();
    this.contentElement = document.createElement(`div`);
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (this.props.children !== prevProps.children) {
      ReactDOM.render(
        React.Children.only(this.props.children),
        this.contentElement
      );
      this.infoWindowRef.current.infowindow.setContent(this.contentElement);
    }
  }

  render() {
    return <InfoWindow ref={this.infoWindowRef} {...this.props} />;
  }
}
```

Now once `InfoWindow` replaced with `InfoWindowEx` event handlers could be attached to Component children:

```
<InfoWindowEx
        marker={this.state.activeMarker}
        visible={this.state.showingInfoWindow}>
        <button type="button" onClick={this.showDetails}>
            Show details
        </button>
</InfoWindowEx>
```

[**Demo**](https://codesandbox.io/s/24m1yrr4mj)

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what i want. I always do wrong things with the context of components.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an updated implementation of Vadim Gremyachev's answer using React hooks:

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { InfoWindow } from "google-maps-react";

export default function InfoWindowEx(props) {
  const infoWindowRef = React.createRef();
  const contentElement = document.createElement(`div`);
  useEffect(() => {
    ReactDOM.render(React.Children.only(props.children), contentElement);
    infoWindowRef.current.infowindow.setContent(contentElement);
  }, [props.children]);
  return <InfoWindow ref={infoWindowRef} {...props} />;
}
```

Implementation JSX stays the same :)

```
<InfoWindowEx
        marker={this.state.activeMarker}
        visible={this.state.showingInfoWindow}>
        <button type="button" onClick={this.showDetails}>
            Show details
        </button>
</InfoWindowEx>
```

Cheers!

Answer (score -1):

You can simply use <a href="/to-your-desired-page"

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).