# google-maps-react infoWindow onChange issues

Tags: reactjs, state, onchange, infowindow, google-maps-react

[How to add a button in infowindow with google-maps-react?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53615413/how-to-add-a-button-in-infowindow-with-google-maps-react#new-answer?newreg=818bbda9d1044464b89180ec782943de)

Hello, I'm writing a React app, I was having an issue with changing state inside the InfoWindow from google-maps-react, the solution above helped me get through that hurdle.

Right now however, I'm having an issue with wanting to edit the content inside my InfoWindowEx component. Using the method above I am able to change the state of a text box inside the InfoWindowEx, however, when I click on the text box and I type it will let me type 1 letter and then I will have to click the text box again if I want to type the next letter, etc. I think this issue has to do with state.

I don't know if there is a solution to this, I have been trying a lot of different things, but hopefully someone can help me know what is going on.

Here is my InfoWindowEx component:

```
<InfoWindowEx
      key={currentInfoWindow.id}
      id={currentInfoWindow.id}
      marker={this.state.activeMarker}
      visible={this.state.showingInfoWindow}
      selectedPlace={this.state.selectedPlace}
      onInfoWindowClose={this.onInfoWindowClose}
    >

      <div >
        {infoWindowEditBoxes}
        {infoWindowContent}

      </div>
    </InfoWindowEx>
```

the Edit boxes are rendering in conditional statements here are they:

```
if (this.state.editButton) {
      infoWindowEditBoxes = (

        <div>
          <input key={this.props.marker}  id="editedName" type="text" placeholder="New Bathroom Name"  onChange={this.handleTextBoxState}></input>
          <input key={this.props.marker}  id="editedLocationName" type="text" placeholder="New Bathroom Location" onChange={this.handleTextBoxState}></input>
          <button onClick={() => this.handleSubmitChangesButtonState()}>Submit Changes</button>
        </div>
      );
    }
    else {
      infoWindowEditBoxes = null
    }
```

and here is my state change function:

```
 handleTextBoxState = (evt) => {
    const stateToChange = {}
    stateToChange[evt.target.id] = evt.target.value
    this.setState(stateToChange)
    console.log(stateToChange)
  }
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I believe component state is getting updated properly in your example, apparently this behavior is related with `InfoWindowEx` component itself. The way how it is implemented, `setState()` causes to a *re-render* `InfoWindow` component which leads to losing input focus.

You could consider the following *updated version* of component which prevents re-rendering of info window if it has been already opened:

```
export default class InfoWindowEx extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isOpen: false
    };
    this.infoWindowRef = React.createRef();
    this.containerElement = document.createElement(`div`);
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (this.props.children !== prevProps.children) {
      ReactDOM.render(
        React.Children.only(this.props.children),
        this.containerElement
      );
      this.infoWindowRef.current.infowindow.setContent(this.containerElement);
      this.setState({
        isOpen: true
      });
    }
  }

  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    if (this.state.isOpen) {
      return this.props.marker.position.toString() !== nextProps.marker.position.toString();
    }
    return true;
  }

  infoWindowClose(){
    this.setState({
      isOpen: false
    });
  }


  render() {
    return <InfoWindow onClose={this.infoWindowClose.bind(this)} ref={this.infoWindowRef} {...this.props} />;
  }
}
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/q9rvz0vpjq)